# What would the curl of a longitudinal wave mean?

Tags: waves

Is the curl of longitudinal waves even defined? Would the curls of a longitudinal wave and a transverse wave be different in any way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a transverse wave moving along the $z$ axis and polarised along the $x$ axis we would write the equation as something like:

$$ \mathbf A(t,z) = A_0 \sin(\omega t - kz) \hat{\mathbf x} $$

And as described in [Curl of an electromagnetic wave](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/119776/curl-of-an-electromagnetic-wave) the curl of this is:

$$ \nabla \times \mathbf A = \frac{\partial A_x}{\partial z} \hat{\bf y} = -kA_0 \cos (\omega t - kz) \hat{\bf y} $$

For a longitudinal wave the equation would be:

$$ \mathbf A(t,z) = A_0 \sin(\omega t - kz) \hat{\mathbf z} $$

I'll leave it as an exercise for the reader to show that curl of this is zero.